# How to stop Jquery from running more than once until the script is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I have a search icon that when hovered over it opens the searchbox and when mouseleaves for it to close the searchbar. however I don't understand how to make it run once before running it again.

HTML

```
<div id="search-container">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnSearch" value="Go" id="ctl00_btnSearch" class="trigger searchbutton search-bg">
    <div class="search-bar">
        <input name="ctl00$txtSearch" type="text" id="ctl00_txtSearch" class="searchbox" value="Search" onfocus="this.value=''">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-container .trigger').mouseover(function() {
        $('section .search-bar input').animate({width:"150px"}, 750, function(){
            $(this).find('input').first().focus();
        });     
        $('.search-bar').animate({width:"185px"}, 750, function(){
            $(this).find('input').first().focus();
        });
        $("#search-container .trigger").mouseleave(function(){
            $("section .search-bar input, .search-bar").animate({width:"0px"}, 750, function(){
                $(this).find('input').first().focus();
            }); 
        });     
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fmrfL/

Comment: Your demo doesn't work because you have not specified the JQuery library. You should also include your javascript in the question

Comment: yep you didn import Jquery and it's not clear when you want to make appear the search box and when you want it do disappear

Comment: "how to make it run once before running it again." You mean, when page loads ? or ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code inside your function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-container .trigger').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('section .search-bar input').stop(true,true).animate({width:"150px"}, 750, function(){
            $(this).find('input').first().focus();
        });     
        $('.search-bar').stop(true,true).animate({width:"185px"}, 750, function(){
            $(this).find('input').first().focus();
        });
      });
      $("#search-container .trigger").mouseleave(function(e){
           $("section .search-bar input, .search-bar").stop(true,true).animate({width:"0px"}, 750,                         
              function(){
               $(this).find('input').first().focus();
            }); 
       });
 });
```

Comment: Basically Jquery Stop method does the trick. Check [Jquery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)